# Dropdownlist inside Updatepanel not passing selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a Gridview that has a hide/show panel. Inside the Panel there is a dropdown and a button. On button press I need the selected value of the dropdown, but I keep getting the first item, no matted what is selected.

I have been investigating the issue and it is to do with the panel control. If I place the dropdown outside the panel, everything works as intended. But dropdown only passes the first value when inside the panel.

Here is my code:

ASP Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DD.aspx.cs" Inherits="DD" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <title></title>
       <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on("click", '[src*=plus]', function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
            $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
        });

        $(document).on("click", '[src*=minus]', function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
            $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();

        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                                     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Requests]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Staff]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="RequestID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestID" HeaderText="RequestID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RequestID" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                        <img runat="server" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none"  UpdateMode="Conditional">

                            <ContentTemplate>                
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
       <asp:Button runat="server" ID="test" OnClick="test_Click" />
                         </ContentTemplate>     </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# Code

```
protected void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    DropDownList referalDD = gvr.FindControl("DD1") as DropDownList;
    string www = referalDD.SelectedItem.Text;
    string qqq = referalDD.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue

Comment: are you checking `IsPostBack` condition in `Page_Load` event?

Comment: My guess is, you can bind your datasource from code inside `IsPostBack` check. This may fix

Comment: IsPostBack is being hit each time I press the button.  Could this cause the resetting of the DD1? If so how do I deal with it?

Comment: `IsPostBack` check won't allow if the event is triggered from `UpdatePannel` but I am not sure about setting `DataSource` from aspx page, I mean how it will get loaded.

Comment: I have even tried populating the DD from rowdatabind event of the gridview. It populates fine, but still only returns the first item in the Dropdown.

Comment: When you click on the button is your gridview reloading? Check that

Comment: Yeah, it seems the page is refreshing. But I have text boxes next to the Dropdown and I can get their value without an issue. I do want the page to reload, but after I have taken the values I need.

Comment: Page will always do postback in aspx. So try loading the grid only if it is full postback.

Comment: If that was the issue, would I loose the text from the text boxes too?

Comment: Usually all the form field values like textbox values will be stored in the viewstate. When the page did postback, this will get the values from the viewstate and restore into respective fields. In the case like `GridView` or custom control, if the code is written like load these on page load, then when the postback happens, it will hit the page load event again. So it will again reload the data and the actual data which is inside these controls will be lost.

Comment: Show the code where you populate the grid and ddl, so we can pinpoint the problem. Although, if the reason for panel is only to show/hide, I would suggest on using placeholder instead.

Comment: @niko,  the asp file above has all the code.  The gridview is populated in the asp page using datasource.  Same for the dd1.  Even if I manually add items (in asp end)  to the dd1,  I still keep getting the first item returned.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have found a work around  / solution. Thanks to Niko for the placeholder suggestion. **I got rid of this code:**

```
<img runat="server" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
```

and the related Jquery

```
$(document).on("click", '[src*=plus]', function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
    $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
});

$(document).on("click", '[src*=minus]', function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
    $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();

})
```

**Added a placeholder around the updatepanel and a Image button**

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ShowHide" ImageUrl="~/images/plus.png" OnClick="ShowHide_Click"  />
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible="false">
```

And this code for the button click event.

```
protected void ShowHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    PlaceHolder ph = gvr.FindControl("PlaceHolder1") as PlaceHolder;
    if (btn.ImageUrl.ToString() == "~/images/plus.png")
    {
        ph.Visible = true;
        btn.ImageUrl = "~/images/minus.png";
    }
    else
    {
        ph.Visible = false;
        btn.ImageUrl = "~/images/plus.png";
    }

}
```

**Note:**  After further testing the whole issue was to do with UpdatePanel having this code  **Style="display: none"** As soon as I removed this, everything worked. But I added the placeholder for by show/Hide feature.